# LNK2019 how to solve in the case? Everything seems to be correct

Tags: c++, oop, linker-errors

I have that common LNK2019 error and can not figure out what is wrong.

Here is my Solution Explorer:

[image]

Here is my `Rectangle.cpp`:

```
class Rectangle
{
    public:
        int getArea()
        {
            return this->width*this->height;
        }
        int width;
        int height;
};
```

Here is my `Rectangle.h`:

```
#pragma once
class Rectangle
{
    public:
        int getArea();
        int width;
        int height;
};
```

Here is my `Functions.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rectangle.h";

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Rectangle r3{ 2, 3 };
    cout << r3.getArea();

    return 0;
}
```

I am very new to C++ and it seems I did everything correctly, but still I am getting an error.

Comment: Why are you redefining the `Rectangle` class in the cpp file?  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579930/separating-class-code-into-a-header-and-cpp-file

Comment: What is he class?

Comment: @ohidano he means the class. See my answer! =)

Comment: @NathanOliver, that helped. Now I have no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rectangle.cpp should be like this:

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

int Rectangle::getArea() {
  return this->width*this->height;
}
```

You shouldn't redefine the class definition in the source file, since you already have it in the header file!

Comment: And now I am getting LNK1120 and the same 2019 along.

Comment: What exactly do you mean @ohidano? Did you include the header in the source file, like you did in your `main()`?

Comment: I solved the issue. It seems like I have to use the word **class** exactly once in `.h` file and I can do not mention member fields at all when I write a class implementation. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yeah @ohidano, like my answer states!

Answer (score 2):

When you want to write the body of a class function, you need to write it this way :

```
#include "Rectangle.h"
int Rectangle::getArea()
{
    return this->width*this->height;
}
```

You do not need to redefine your class into the cpp file.
You define everything inside the header (.h, .hpp), you include it inside the cpp file (`#include "Rectangle.h"`) but you must not redeclare everything in the header file.

By the way, since you are writing a method, you can access member variables directly by `width` and you do not need to use `this->width`.

However, I recommand you to use a convention when you are writing your own classes.
My convention is to prefix member variable by a `m`. (In your case it gives you `mWidth` or `mHeight`).

There is other people that have other conventions like `m_variable` or `variable_`.

Comment: So, in `.cpp` class file only an implementation of methods should go, am I right?

Comment: @ohidano yes, that's right! Antoine, nice answer! :)

Comment: It depends on what you need. But I would say to process that way.
One class = 2 files : one header like you do (it is a kind of plan) and the construction inside the *.cpp. After, it depends on what you need. But since you are beginning C++, I can advice you to do like we both said :
header = class and prototypes of methods.
cpp = implementation