# Separating class with nested types into a header and source

Tags: c++, class, header

There is a theme - [Separating class code into a header and cpp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579930/separating-class-code-into-a-header-and-cpp-file)

It describes how to separate a class with variables and methods to .h and .cpp

But it's a simple one.

Say I have this in main.cpp

```
int main() {
    class Filth {
        int a, b;
        void pra() { std::cout << a; }
        class Frank {

            int sacrifices;

            void praisChinChin() { std::cout << "DARK LORD IS COMMINGGGGGG"; }
        }
    };
}
```

And how do I write THIS class (Filth) into a .h and .cpp so I dont get "undefined reference" and any other mistake?

And how exactly does it work (why I should write this exact code, what exactly does it do to my program)?

Comment: Sorry, but your indentation is horrible and I hope it's because you didn't pay attention when you posted your code here (it's very unreadable).

Comment: ಠ_ಠ it has no snippet, and there should be #include <iostream> as the first line. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: A `class` defined within a function is not supported in standard C++. Might be time to dust off your favourite C++ text book. Also, try to make your example less puerile.

Comment: @Bathsheba Actually it is.

Comment: Local classes are absolutely Standard C++. I think it might be time for *you* to dust off your text book.

Comment: @Puppy: Touche. Will be sneezing for the rest of the evening.

Answer (score 1):

1. frank.cpp

   ```
   #include "frank.h"
   #include <iostream>

   void Frank::praisChinChin() {
       std::cout << "DARK LORD IS COMMINGGGGGG"; 
   }
   ```
2. frank.h

   ```
   #pragma once

   class Frank {
       int sacrifices = 0;
     public:
       void praisChinChin();
   };
   ```
3. filth.cpp

   ```
   #include "filth.h"
   #include <iostream>

   void Filth::pra() {
       std::cout << a; 
   }
   ```
4. filth.h

   ```
   #pragma once

   class Filth {
       int a = 0;
       int b = 0;
       void pra();
   };
   ```
5. test.cpp

   ```
   #include "frank.h"

   int main() {
       Frank f;
       f.praisChinChin();
   }
   ```

Comment: So, the classes are separated, and we have a Frank class and a Filth class, in condition of Frank{} Flith{} , but not Flank{Filth{}}?

Comment: Well, actually that was a part [I half overlooked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257804/separating-class-code-that-has-another-class-in-it-into-a-header-and-cpp-file/46258065?noredirect=1#comment79479719_46258072). From the code you gave there's absolutely no reason why `Filth` needs to be nested inside `Frank`, so you'd normally not do that. Otherwise, you can simply stick with: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25551674/

Comment: Real thanks. That is useful, about the methods - every time i write the definition in .cpp , i should be doing  void Class::Class2......::Methodname(){}? Or is there a way to get the code look like I created it in main.cpp (like in example - method in class, that is in another class, structured, no :: :: :: :: :: every time i describe (write the actual code) of a method that is on some depth (in-classed) level)? Real thank you again.

Comment: Yes. Though you can - using discretion - define them inline: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25551807/ -- your [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will have all the details

Comment: So what you are doing in this example is you just copypaste code from main.cpp to .h, and it works just fine?

Comment: No. It only works for inline definitions. Like I said, a c++ book is going to be indispensable

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semi colon at the end of class Frank.
It should compile after that.

To separate the class into .h and .cpp file you should make you function non local to the main function.

Header file might look like this.

```
class Filth
{
    int a, b;
    void pra();

    class Frank 
    {
        int sacrifices;
        void praisChinChin();
    };
};
```

And the cpp file

```
void Filth::pra()
{
    std::cout << a;
}

void Filth::Frank::praisChinChin()
{
    std::cout << "DARK LORD IS COMMINGGGGGG";
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure about the "why should I write the exact code". But at the moment your code is not really doing anything. You need to create objects of your classes and call member functions, for it to have any real effect.

Comment: You're missing quite a bit of critical mechanics. Also "Should look like"? "Could look like" is a bit more to the point

Comment: @sehe I agree. Edited. Thanks

Comment: Still - not showing include guards or directives, not making anything public, not initializing non-static data members etc :) Kudos for getting the nested type right (I misread that)

Comment: All of us were guilty of that at some point. My intention was to explain class declarations and definitions without changing too much of the original code.