# Visual Studio console debugging wrong file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have created an empty project and added two ( .cpp) items inside the project. Keep in mind that I am a beginner in C++ Visual Studio, so I have not used any code to somehow connect the two files.

**Problem:** The debugger was fine for debugging my first file, but when I open my second file and start running by clicking "Local Windows Debugger" (clicked when I was inside the second file), it will still keep on running the first file whether there was a bug or not.

When I looked at the debug window after I hit "Local Windows Debugger", I saw the file path pointing to the first file.

**I have tried:** Closing the first file completely, closing visual studio and opening my second file from my folder path, turning off the break-point in the first file and turning on in the second file.

**I would like to know:** How can I just run the second file? Do I have to use the command prompt to keep my two items in the empty project separate? I am using Windows 10 by the way.

I searched for my problem, but I had a hard time looking for a guide that gave a solution

Comment: What's your folder/file hierarchy and what are the contents of both scripts? [You should check here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need a guide on good Q/A etiquette.

Comment: The start of the program is always the `main` function. Each project has only one `main` in all its files.

Comment: @DeiDei jeez, I had both of my files have a main function. Should I use void as an alternative for my second file?

Comment: @JamesWhyte My apologies, I did not realize that the content of my code as in having two main functions would affect which file would debug first. Do you know a good read on different file starters and how I can get a specific file in a project to debug first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue:

Dracep cannot debug one of two files they have. This is due to them having a main function definition in both files, causing the editor to favour one over the other.

### Solution:

By having a third, dedicated entry point in your application (I.E. having a single point of entry you then include the other files), you can decide which file you are going to debug at any given time.

For example, having a file called `main.cpp` which then includes the other two files by using `#include "filename.h"`.

From there you can include the file and make you code checks by calling the functions in that file  rather than having a main and stepping down through it, causing long term issues of scalability.

Please see [this question on separating your logic from your definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579930/separating-class-code-into-a-header-and-cpp-file), as the answer marked correct is the standard for most C++ projects you will find.

That way, you could do something like the following:

```
#include "File1.h"
#include "File2.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    File1Class file1Class;
    File2Class file2Class;
    //Do whatever tests you like with either.
}
```

Comment: By following this method and separating your logic from your definitions, you can debug to your heart's content without significant issue. It's a bit of a pain to learn, but Headers and CPP files are exactly what you should strive for; they make life EZ-PZ. ;D

Comment: Thanks! Up to now I have focused on only the basic syntax of C++, but it's showing that I need to look at the fundamentals as well.