# Declaration Vs. Definition for classes

Tags: c++

I have a quick question about class declaration vs. class definition.

So, I can think of four different scenarios of class code:

Which ones qualify as declarations and which as definitions? Why?

TIA.

1)

```
class foo_empty{};
```

2,3)

```
class foo_NoMemDef{
   int f1(); //Member function declaration(?), no body
  //int i; (consider including this as a separate case 3)
};
```

4)

```
class foo_final{
   int f2(){}
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which ones qualify as declarations and which as definitions?

All examples show class definitions (that are also declarations). A class declaration that is not a definition looks like this:

```
class Foo;
```

Once you "open/close" a class by `{` and `}`, you are providing a definition.

Comment: Well, some definitions are also declarations.

Comment: @UKMonkey But that is only for the member function `f1`. The class itself is defined.

Comment: @lubgr I see what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: @lubgr Can you have a look at the first answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579930/separating-class-code-into-a-header-and-cpp-file . It says to declare a class in header file but in the code has { } meaning it is a definition right?

Comment: Yes, I disagree with the wording of this answer. In the header file, it's a class definition (which is also a declaration), while in the implementation file, you have the definitions of the member functions.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It had me doubting myself!

Answer (score 2):

All of your examples are class definitions, as they all finally define the class; you cannot extend the class definition later on any more. Note that providing an implementation for one of the class' methods does not extend the class' interface and hence does not influence the definition of the class itself.

A class declaration introducing a tag "foo" of type "class" would be

```
class foo;
```

Comment: It is correct that they are all definitions, but they are also all declarations.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the insight on interface being fixed in definition.

Answer (score 0):

those are all definitions with declarations. a declaration (by itself) in c++ has no {}.

in a header file you might say something like

```
public class student{

public void UpdateGpa(float grade, int credits);

private float gpa;
private string name;
private int credits;

}
```

the above example student is defined and the updategpa function is declared. it would then generally be defined in a cpp file. where it might say

```
public void UpdateGpa(float grade, int credits){

this.credits+=credits;

gpa= gpa formula

}
```

this would be the definition of the UpdateGpa Function. things are declared if you cant see the function and know how it works from just what you're seeing. things are defined if there is code provided detailing what the function does.

Comment: Declarations _can_ also be definitions, so your opening statement is not entirely correct.