# Are all of the C++ headers, a class?

Tags: c++

I was reading C++ from Deitel's book, which I reached this part:

> Some functions, such as main , are not members of a class. These functions are called global
>   functions. We introduce various functions from the  header here to present the
>   concept of global functions that do not belong to a particular class.

and after saying this block (this block itself is exactly under Math library), it introduced some functions such as **sqrt()** which belongs to **cmath** header and finally it said that all functions which belongs to **cmath** are global!

So, this is my question: At the top we said that all functions that don't belong to any class, are global functions; but then it said that all functions which are related to **cmath** are global! So isn't it a contradiction? 
I mean if we accept this, it means that **not all of the headers are classes**. Is it right?

[image: C++ Deitel Book]

Comment: @uneven_mark so what are headers? We can use headers to include our classes. I mean one of their use is for including classes, so what are the other ones?

Comment: Did you miss the chapter describing how preprocessor works and what header files are? They are just files containing chunks of program text that are glued by preprocessor when they are included into other files.

Comment: One practice of declaring and defining Class at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9579974/5595995.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Header files doesn't on their own introduce a new scope or namespace, or indeed any class.

Header files included with the preprocessor `#include` directive are basically copy-pasted as-is into the [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) for the later stages of the compiler to parse.

In short, there's really no difference between source and header files. Both can contain function or class declarations or definitions.

---

A very simplified example.

Lets say you have the header file `a.h` which contains a single function declaration:

```
void a_function();
```

Then you have a source file which include the header file:

```
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
    a_function();
}
```

After preprocessing the translation unit would look something like this:

```
void a_function();

int main()
{
    a_function();
}
```

The function `a_function` isn't part of a class, it's a global function.

Comment: That sample code, totally solved the problem. Thank you by the way ;)

Answer (score 4):

A header is a file, a class is a type introduced by `class` or `struct`. While people often put each class in a dedicated header file for organization, there is no specific relationship between them. For example, `<cmath>` is just a bag of global (or, more precisely, namespace-scope) math-related functions, no "math" class needed.

> We can use headers to include our classes. I mean one of their use is for including classes, so what are the other ones?

We use headers to include various declarations (nitpick shield: definitions as well), not just class declarations. These can be classes, typedefs, functions, variables, named constants, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to all the other answers you have gotten, I would like to show you a few examples that should drive home that `#include ...` is just a copy-paste mechanism.

I have three files:

CodeBody.h

```
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

Numbers.h

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

and main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> bla = {
#include "Numbers.h"
    };

    for (auto a : bla) {
#include "CodeBody.h"
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Now, I would say that pasting code in like I did here with CodeBody.h is somewhat questionable, and you should not do that. But using an include file to populate an array or other data structure is used reasonably often, for example in digital signal processing where you use a dedicated program to calculate the coefficients for a filter, save them to a file, and then import them into your program with an include.

Answer (score 2):

``**not all of the headers are classes**'', that's the point.

Headers are just files (ie. code containers). This is used to help modularization or code management: put different part of the code in different files.

A class is a language construct. Such a construct can be put in any file you want (and worst can be dispatched in different files).

To be more clear: headers are just sheets of paper, and classes things that you can write on it.

Comment: nitpick: not any header is a class, while "not all of the headers are classes" sounds as if there are some headers that are classes