# how to use objects of nested classes

Tags: c++, class, nested

I have a class in a header file:

`dmx.h`

```cpp
// dmx.h
#ifndef dmx_h
#define dmx_h

class Dmx {
  public:
    Dmx() {   
    }                                    
    // some functions and variables
    void channelDisplay() {
    }

    class touchSlider;     
};
     
#endif
```

and a nested class in another header file:

`touchSlider.h`

```cpp
// touchSlider.h
#ifndef touchSlider_h
#define touchSlider_h

#include "dmx.h"

class Dmx::touchSlider{
  private:
  // some variables

  public:
  touchSlider(){                       
  }
  // some functions
  void printChannel() {
  }
};
   

#endif
```

And I initialize my objects in my main file like this:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "dmx.h"               
#include "touchSlider.h"

Dmx dmx[10] = {Dmx(1), Dmx(2),Dmx(3), Dmx(4), Dmx(5), Dmx(6), Dmx(7), Dmx(8), Dmx(9), Dmx(10)};

Dmx::touchSlider slider[10] = {50,130,210,290,370,50,130,210,290,370};  

// functions:
Dmx::touchSlider::printChannel() {}
Dmx::channelDisplay() {}
```

There is an error message when compiling saying: `'class Dmx' has no member named 'slider'`

Could someone explain to me how this works correctly?

Comment: `class Dmx { /* ...*/ class touchSlider { /* This is a definition */ }; };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that inside the class `dmx` you already provided a definition for the nested class `touchSlider` since you used `{}` and so you're trying to redefine it inside `touchSlider.h`.

To **solve** this you can provide the declarations for the member functions of `touchSlider` in the header and then define those member functions inside a source file named `touchSlider.cpp` as shown below:

**dmx.h**

```
// dmx.h
#ifndef dmx_h
#define dmx_h

class Dmx {
  public:
    Dmx() {   
    }  
    Dmx(int){
    }
    // some functions and variables
    void channelDisplay() {
    }

    class touchSlider{
        private:
        // some variables

        public:
            touchSlider(); //declaration 
           touchSlider(int);//declaration
            
            // some functions
            void printChannel();//declaration
    };
};

#endif
```

**touchSlider.cpp**

```
#include "dmx.h"
//default ctor implementation
Dmx::touchSlider::touchSlider(){
 
}
//definition
void Dmx::touchSlider::printChannel() {
  
}
//definition
Dmx::touchSlider::touchSlider(int)
{
    
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/0XswSpiz2)

Comment: I just did that but now I have the problem in my main file when compiling that`'class Dmx' has no member named 'slider'`

Comment: @LastHerd See the [working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/0XswSpiz2). You need to provide the declarations for the member functions of `touchSlider` in the header and then you can define them in a source file called `touchSilder.cpp` as shown in my answer above.

Comment: I can also provide the declarations in my main file, right? I have a display with touchscreen (whose code is in my main file), then it should work too.

Comment: @LastHerd Do you mean member function definitions? If yes, then yes you can provide the definition for the member function `printChannel` and constructors inside the `main.cpp` file. Just make sure that across the whole program you provide only one definition for them though.

Comment: yes i meant member functions. It works now. But the only problem now is to create an object array of `touchSlider` INSIDE the `Dmx `class, where would i do this? @Anoop Rana

Comment: @LastHerd Take a look at [Separating class code into a header and cpp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579930/separating-class-code-into-a-header-and-cpp-file). It should help. If you still have follow up question, feel free to ask a new separate question describing your problem. As there is word limit in the comment section.