# How call included libraries functions?

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

I have C++ shared library like this:

```
extern "C"{

   #include <foo.h>

   int test(int a){
      return 1;
   }

}
```

I can lookup and call function `int test(int a);`, but exported C functions in the included library (`foo.h`) are not visible to call.

How can I make all `foo.h` C functions visible and call them?

I'm using CMake for building the project.

Comment: I could be reading this wrong, but usually the `extern "C"` trick is to allow C to call C++ functions, not the other way around.

Comment: @user4581301 It's used for both. You put external function declarations in there so it won't mangle the names when it tries to call them.

Comment: If your header file contains source code (i.e., function definitions), you should split them into a source file like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9579974/16941344), let's say `foo.cpp`. And then you should create the library file along with your present source codes with cmake like this: `add_library(library_name foo.cpp ${OTHER_SOURCE_CODES})`

Comment: The declarations in foo.h also need to be surrounded by `extern "C"`.

Comment: I shot myself in the face once by trying to hide the C++ functions in the .so and only expose the C interface, and forgot that the C interface was still C++ code - and thus hidden.

Answer (score 0):

> I can lookup and call function int test(int a);, but exported C functions in the included library (foo.h) are not visible to call.

You can't see all functions you defined in your header file because they are not used. Here is a small example:

```cpp
// header_only.h
#ifndef HEADER_ONLY_H
#define HEADER_ONLY_H

extern "C" {

// these functions are used
inline int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
inline int sub(int a, int b) { return a - b; }

// there functions are not
inline int mult(int a, int b) { return a * b; }

}

#endif // !HEADER_ONLY_H
```

Let's try to call functions in it:

```cpp
// test.cpp
#include "header_only.h"

extern "C" {

int test() {
  int a = 5;
  int b = 4;
  int add_result = sum(a, b);
  int sub_result = sub(a, b);

  return a * b;
}

}
```

Please notice that, we only called `sum` and `sub`, while `mult` is defined but not used.

Now let's compile and link the object file into a library file:

```bash
# compile the source file into object file
❯ g++ -c  test.cpp -o test.o
# create a library file
❯ ar rcs libtest.a test.o
# print all symbol names
❯ nm -U libtest.a

test.o:
0000000000000074 T _sub
0000000000000054 T _sum
0000000000000000 T _test
0000000000000000 t ltmp0
0000000000000098 s ltmp1
```

As you can see, `mult` is not compiled into the lib. And if we write a `main` function like this:

```cpp
// test_lib.cpp
extern "C" {

extern int test();

int main() {
  test();
  return 0;
}
}
```

Compile with commands:

```bash
❯ g++ test_lib.cpp libtest.a -o main
❯ ./main
❯ echo $?
0
```

Things will work just fine. But if you try to directly use `mult` in `test_lib.cpp` without including `header_only.h`:

```cpp
// test_lib.cpp
extern "C" {

int main() {
  // test();
  mult(3, 4);

  return 0;
}
}
```

Let's compile it:

```bash
❯ g++ test_lib.cpp libtest.a -o main
test_lib.cpp:5:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mult'
  mult(3, 4);
```

---

If you want to use all the functions you defined in your header file, the best choice is to split them into a header file and a source file, just like [this answer mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9579974/16941344). And compile the source code you splited out(let's say `foo.cpp`) with other source files.

```cpp
// header_only.h
#ifndef HEADER_ONLY_H
#define HEADER_ONLY_H

extern "C" {

// these functions are used
int sum(int a, int b);
int sub(int a, int b);

// there functions are not
int mult(int a, int b);
}

#endif // !HEADER_ONLY_H
```

```cpp
//header_only.cpp
#include "header_only.h"

extern "C" {

int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

int sub(int a, int b) { return a - b; }

int mult(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
}
```

Other source files are not modified. Let's compile again:

```bash
❯ g++ -c header_only.cpp test.cpp
❯ ar rcs libtest.a test.o header_only.o
❯ nm -a libtest.a

test.o:
                 U _sub
                 U _sum
0000000000000000 T _test
0000000000000000 t ltmp0
0000000000000058 s ltmp1

header_only.o:
0000000000000040 T _mult
0000000000000020 T _sub
0000000000000000 T _sum
0000000000000000 t ltmp0
0000000000000060 s ltmp1
```

You can see that all the symbols are exported. And you can use `mult` in your `main` function:

```bash
❯ cat test_lib.cpp
#include "header_only.h"

extern "C" {

int main() {
  // test();
  mult(3, 4);

  return 0;
}
}
❯ g++ libtest.a test_lib.cpp
❯ ./a.out
❯ echo $?
0
```

You can do the same in CMake. Just do what is shown above, and add the file name of the source code you splited out in `foo.h` into `add_library`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(test_link)

add_library(link header_only.cpp test.cpp)

add_executable(main test_lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main link)
```

Let's build the project:

```bash
❯ cmake -B build
cmake-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 14.0.3.14030022
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 14.0.3.14030022
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/liuyuan/Desktop/test/build
❯ cmake --build build
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/link.dir/header_only.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/link.dir/test.cpp.o
[ 60%] Linking CXX static library liblink.a
[ 60%] Built target link
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/test_lib.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable main
[100%] Built target main
❯ ./build/main
❯ echo $?
0
```