# Need help understaning how to use #include with multiple files

Tags: c++

`#include` file `"C:\USERS\SAMPO\PROJECTS\calculator_functions.cpp"` includes itself.

I'm new to multiple files, so it's all a little confusing, being new to C++ as well.

calculator.cpp

```
/* 
1st file is main code
2nd file is classes
3rd files is functions
*/



/* what's needed

User input
  -get input
  -log input


sort into Numbers and operations
  -use blank space to divide
    -sort numbers
    -sort operations
      (if multiple operations use gems)


perform operations with numbers


output final result
  -print output
  -log output


start new input
  -new blank line

  
Additional features:
clear previous lines

*/

#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include "calculator_functions.cpp"
#include "classes.h"

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  Initialize user_input;
  user_input.getInput;
  user_input.append;
  user_input.print;
  
}
```

classes.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "calculator_functions.cpp"


class Initialize 
{

  public: 
    //defining variables
    string user_input;
  
    // Gets input from user
    getInput(user_input);

    // Adds input to data list
    append_input(user_input);

    // FOR TESTING Prints result
    print(input_list);

};
```

calculator_functions.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include "classes.h"


using namespace std;

void getInput(string user_input)
{
  getline(cin, user_input);

}

list<string> append(string user_input, list<string> input_list = {}) 
{
  input_list.push_back(user_input);
  return input_list;
}

void print(list<string> input_list) 
{
  std::cout << input_list;
}
```

There's not much information online besides `#pragma once`, but that didn't work, either. I tried it in every file separately, and every file with it, but nothing worked.

Comment: Don't include source (`.cpp`) files.

Comment: Also remember that function of a class needs to be scoped. So when you define (implement) the `getInput` function of the `Initialize` class, you need to use `Initialize::getInput`. This should have been clearly taught in your beginners material. Also, you have to use the full type of all arguments, everywhere. Even when you're only declaring a function.

Comment: All in all, you seem to have quite a lot of misunderstandings about classes, objects and members. I feel you should take a few steps back and learn those basics first before trying to use multiple files, both source and headers. And if you're serious about learning C++, then please invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). They will be worth the cost.

Comment: Many bad programming habits in the code. I would recommend  a [Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Also [How to separate a class and its member functions into header and source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579930/how-to-separate-a-class-and-its-member-functions-into-header-and-source-files)

Comment: Read up on "shunting yard algorithm" in order to get the operator precedence working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`#include` statements should be used to pull in *header* files, not *source* files.  You need to *compile* your `.cpp` files individually, and they should `#include` whatever `.h` files they need.

Also, your `calculator_functions.cpp` file is not implementing the class methods, it is implementing standalone functions instead.  You need to prefix the class method definitions with the class name that they belong to.  And the methods to match what you specified in the class declaration.

Also, your `main()` function needs to actually *call* the class methods, not just *refer* to them.

Also, there is no `operator<<` defined for printing a `std::list`, so you need to loop through the `list` yourself printing its items.

With that said, your source files should look more like this:

calculator.cpp

```
/* 
1st file is main code
2nd file is classes
3rd files is functions
*/



/* what's needed

User input
  -get input
  -log input


sort into Numbers and operations
  -use blank space to divide
    -sort numbers
    -sort operations
      (if multiple operations use gems)


perform operations with numbers


output final result
  -print output
  -log output


start new input
  -new blank line

  
Additional features:
clear previous lines

*/

#include "classes.h"

int main() 
{
  Initialize user_input;
  user_input.getInput();
  user_input.appendInput();
  user_input.print();  
}
```

classes.h

```
#ifndef ClassesH
#define ClassesH
// or, use '#pragma once' instead, if you prefer...

#include <string>
#include <list>

class Initialize 
{
  public: 
    //defining variables
    std::string user_input;
    std::list<std::string> input_list;
  
    // Gets input from user
    void getInput();

    // Adds input to data list
    void appendInput();

    // FOR TESTING Prints result
    void print();
};

#endif
```

calculator_functions.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "classes.h"

void Initialize::getInput()
{
  std::getline(std::cin, user_input);
}

void Initialize::appendInput() 
{
  input_list.push_back(user_input);
}

void Initialize::print() 
{
  for(const auto &item : input_list)
    std::cout << item << '\n';
}
```

Then, you need to compile `calculator.cpp` and `calculator_functions.cpp`, and then you need to *link* the compiled object files to create the final `.exe` file.