How to separate class to .h and .cpp without need to rewrite entire path
When I define a class in header file, I must write entire it's path for every method. I'd want to still define it as a class. For example:
a.h:
class a {
  void main();
}

a.cpp:
#include "a.h"
class a { // still encapsulate to write without prefix
  void main() {
    // define it
  }
}

This code would give an error but can something similar actually be done?
What I mean is to define code for every method I must write a::main() {} which is not very readable for me. I asked whether it is possible to still define it in a way as in header.

In the code presented you have 2 different classes named a

Related if not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579930/how-to-separate-a-class-and-its-member-functions-into-header-and-source-files

This should be taught early in any decent book, tutorial or class. What resources are you using to learn C++?

If I have "too many" namespaces, I just add a typedef as a shortcut for the class name to the .cpp file.

If your question is how to implement the class methods in the cpp file (out of the declaration in the h file) without having to specify the a:: prefix - it is not possible in C++.

The description "must write entire it's path for every method" is as clear as mud (and certainly not one that would be interpreted the same way by everyone).   What do you mean?

What i mean is to define every unit then i must write "a::main() {}" which is not very readable for me. I asked whether it is possible to still define it as in header.
Though the answers i got:
Use typedef if path is too large
Another way of definions than write with class path not exists

i must write "a::main() {}" which is not very readable for me. I have never felt that way however I have written c++ code for over 30 years and about 2 million lines of code professionally.


What i mean is to define code for every method i must write "a::main() {}" which is not very readable for me.

If you want to implement class methods separatly from the class definition itself (which is the one you have in the h file), the syntax of C++ requires you to use the a:: prefix.
This is true whether you place the method definition in a cpp files, or even in the h file itself.
The only way the syntax allows to implement a method without the prefix with the class name and ::, is if it is implemented inline inside the class definition, but it seems like it will not suit you because then in your case it will not be in cpp file.
There is no other way around it.
Readbility is a subjective matter, but I must say that I (as well as many other experiences C++ programmers) find it very readable.
A side note:
In this specific case you might want to use a namespace instead of a class, to group the functions. See the other answer by @anatolyg for more details.

The thing with classes is, they usually represent objects. In this example, the function main stands by itself - it doesn't work on any object. If so, the proper "container" to hold it is a namespace and not a class.
// a.h
namespace a {
  // declare it
  void main();
}

// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
namespace a {
  // define it
  void main() {
    ...
  }
}

The syntax of a namespace resembles that of a class, but it has two forms: a::main or just main. See examples below.
// other_file.cpp
#include "a.h"

...
// use it
a::main();

// yet_another_file.cpp
#include "a.h"
using namespace a;

...
// use it in another way
main();

In the last example, using namespace a does what you want — it makes the "path" to your function optional.

Probably shouldn't name your function main as that would easily confuse someone with int main()
