# Does the function return type affect the choice of an overload?

Tags: c++, c++11

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34178651/2725810) post, the following method was suggested to define the `operator<<` function for all classes that define a `dump()` member function:

```
template <typename T, typename charT>
auto operator<< (std::basic_ostream<charT> & str, const T & t) -> decltype(t.dump(str))
{
    return t.dump(str);
}
```

How come this function template does not catch all types, including those that don't define a `dump` member function? I mean, is the return type part of the function signature that is taken into account for choosing the overload?

Comment: Technique is called SFINAE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return type per se doesn't matter. The technique proposed relies on SFINAE (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error) to have the overload removed when the declaration would be invalid for an instantiation. That is, when the compiler tries instantiate the above `operator<<()` with a type `T` which doesn't have an accessible `dump(str)` member, the `decltype(t.dump(str))` would be invalid. Instead of failing it decides that this overload won't work and removes it from the candidate overload set.

Once the candidates are collected, overload resolution chooses the best option(s). If the best option is unique, it is selected for being called. If there is no fitting option or there are multiple best matches, it would be an error.

Comment: Would it be correct to say then that SFINAE is not a programming technique, but is rather a compiler technology?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: SFINAE is simply a name given to a combination of C++ language rules. Instead of describing the language rules conspiring to do something useful people refer to "SFINAE" to describe what is being done. I think of SFINAE is a programming technique (control the overload set based on properties of template arguments).

Comment: Without this rule lots of templates couldn't be written. Programmers learnt that they could leverage it to do lots of cool stuff, like checking whether certain member functions etc exist.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is not attributed to overload resolution rules but rather to template argument deduction rules. In particular is attributed to SFINAE (aka substitution failure is not an error).

In template argument deduction the compiler will try to instantiate your function but if input parameter `t` doesn't have a member function `dump`, it won't issue an error but rather it will consider it as substitution failure and thus it will not instantiate the template.