# How to properly overload the "<<" operator in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to make a behavior like `std::cout` has:

```
int a = 10, b = 15, c = 7;
MyBaseClass << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << std::endl;
```

I try to implement some things which I've just read but it doesn't work for me. I want to implement `operator` in one class which I call `MyBaseClass`. I tried this:

```
class MyBaseClass {
    private:
        std::ostream someOut;
    public:
        // My first try:
        std::ostream &operator<< ( std::ostream &out, const std::string &message ) {
        }

        // The second try:
        std::ostream &operator<< ( const std::string &message ) {
            someOut << message << std::endl;
            return someOut;
        }

        void writeMyOut() { 
            std::cout << someOut.str() 
        };
};
```

When I compile this I get: "Call to implicity-deleted default constructor of 'MyBaseClass'" - what do I need to do to fix it?

OS X, Xcode, clang compiler, all is up-to-date.

Comment: Possible duplicate [C++ Beginner - 'friend' functions and << operator overloading: What is the proper way to overload an operator for a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828280/c-beginner-friend-functions-and-operator-overloading-what-is-the-prope)

Comment: I think your second try should work, more or less.  The compile error is probably because `MyBaseClass` has no constructors, but you need one to initialize the`someOut` member.  (I'm not 100% sure that's the problem, but if you provide a constructor for `MyBaseClass`, I think you'll get a little further.  Specifically, I think you'll get far enough to try to write on the uninitialized `std::ostream` called `someOut`.)

Comment: @DaveM. - if I add an empty constructor I get: `Field of type 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') has protected default constructor`

Comment: @Joel: this question is not about creating an `operator<<` to stream a user-defined type (per your duplicate candidate), but about making a type to which other types can be streamed.  It's probably a duplicate too, but harder to find.

Comment: The problem is, you're not initializing the `std::ostream`.  I'm not sure you _can_ create a plain `ostream` -- you generally either create an `ofstream` or an `ostringstream` (maybe now called an `ostrstream`?  I forget.)
Try replacing `std::ostream` with `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: @DaveM.: `ostringstream` is the replacement for the `ostrstream` of yesteryear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to output a variety of value types into the `MyBaseClass` object, so need to support the same set.  I've also changed `someOut` to be a `std::ostringstream`, which is capable of accumulating the output.  You might equally have wanted it to be a `std::ostream&` to a caller-provided stream passed to the constructor....

```
class MyBaseClass {
    private:
        std::ostringstream someOut;
    public:
        ...other functions...
        // The second try:
        template <typename T>
        MyBaseClass& operator<< ( const T& x ) {
            someOut << x;
            return *this;
        }

        void writeMyOut() const { 
            std::cout << someOut.str() 
        };
};
```

Comment: In this case I get: `Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'MyBaseClass'`

Comment: @JavaRunner: have you provided any `MyBaseClass` constructors yourself (perhaps at DaveM's prompting)?  If so, remove them.  With `std::ostream& someOut;` you'd need `MyBaseClass(std::ostream& os) : someOut(os) { }`, but you don't need to specify any constructor for `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works like a charm! It was my fault.

Comment: @JavaRunner: sure, no worries.  Hope you enjoy your C++ coding.  Cheers.