# Why use std::ostream and friend for << operator overloading?

Tags: c++

I want to overload the operator << to print a list using std::cout, for example:

```
std::cout << list 
//ouputs as {1,2,3,..}
```

After searching, I came to know that this can be done using ostream, but I am not sure how this is done. Like why is this necessary to take in ostream as a reference and then return it?

**Operator Overloading function:**

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, List list) 
{
    Node* temp = list.start; //points to the start of the list
    cout<<"{";
    while(temp)
    {
        cout << temp->data; //cout all the data
        if (temp->next != NULL)
            cout << ",";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout<<"}" << endl;
    return os; //returns the ostream
}
```

And I also don't understant why do we have to make that a friend function? If I remove the keyword friend, it gives me an error that << operator is a binary operator. I am using Xcode.

**List.hpp**

```
class List
{
    Node* start;
public:
    List();
    ~List();
    void emptyList();
    void append(int);
    void insert(int, int);
    void print();
    int  length();
    void remove_at(int);
    int get_value_index(int);
    int get_value_at(int);
    List operator-(int); 
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,List); //why friend function??
    List operator=(List);
    List operator+(int);
    List operator+(List);
    int& operator[](const int ind);
    bool operator==(List);
};
```

Comment: The hows and whys are covered in the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2828280/1531971

Comment: return stream from << so that you can chain operations `cout << 42 << mylist << "yo"`

Comment: Just to bring some clarity: you can define `void operator>>(ostream& os);` in your `class List` instead and call it as `list >> cout;`. Not recommended, just to illustrate.

Answer (score 3):

In the operator << overload you shouldn’t use cout, you should use the ostream you are receiving as a parameter, just change the `cout` for `os`. This is because the cout will print that output stream you are returning.

You need to make that operator overload a friend function because even though the operator isn’t a part of the class, it will have access to the class private attributes and functions, so it can access the elements and print them.

Comment: To be clear. If you are able to convert your class to a printable string without accessing private methods or data the `friend` is not needed.  One useful approach to avoiding the `friend` is to define a public `toString()` method on the class and implement  as `os << list.toStringIO;`

Answer (score 1):

The operator `<<` is a binary operator, meaning that it needs one operand on the left-hand side and one on the right-hand side. For example, when you write `cout << "Hello World"` the left-hand side operand is `cout` which is of type `ostream` and the right-hand side operand is the string `"Hello World"`. Similarly, to overload the operator for one of your classes you must define what will be the left-hand side operand and what the right-hand side operand, just as overloading the plus (+) operator, or any other binary operator, requires you to define what are the operands. Therefore, `os` should be used where you have written `cout`, as has already been pointed out in a previous answer, and it will have the "value" `cout` if the left-hand side opernad is `cout`.

As for returning `os`, the reason to do this is in order to be able to chain multiple printing statements. It is possible using integers to write `cout << 3 << 5;`, because initially the first `<<` operator is evaluated, printing 3, then os is returned and is passed as the left-hand side operand to the next `<<`. If the overloaded operator does not return `os`, this will be impossible to do with objects of your class.

Finally, as has already been said, the overload should be a friend of the class because it needs access to its private members, and since it is not a member function of the class, it cannot have it unless it is a friend to it.