# Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'sound_ctl')

Tags: c++, stream

I'm trying to write a `<<` operator. My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
class sound_ctl {
private:
    int _vol;
    bool _status;
public:
    sound_ctl() : _vol(50), _status(false) {};

    void operator++() {
        if (_vol <= 98) {
            _vol += 2;
        }
    }

    void operator--() {
        if (_vol >= 2) {
            _vol -= 2;
        }
    }

    void operator!() {
        _status = !_status;
    }

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os) const {
        os << _status << "Volume: " + _vol << std::endl;
        return os;
    }

};


int main() {
    sound_ctl panel1;
    std::cout << panel1;
}
```

But, the code wont compile with error: `Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'sound_ctl')`

I have a severe lack of understanding of streams in c++, so, understanding the underlying issue would help me greatly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not define an input/output operators as member functions.

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const sound_ctl& sc) {
    os << sc._status << "Volume: " + sc._vol << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

And then declare this function as a friend:

```
class sound_ctl {
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const sound_ctl& sc);
// ...
};
```

Why can't you call output, like so `std::cout << panel1`, in your case? Because the `<<` as you can see is just a syntactic sugar for the function call of the `operator<<()` function. If this function is a member function, then the left-hand-side will be passed as implicit `this`, while the right-hand-side will be the parameter in the parameter list. Means you would have to call the output like so:

```
panel1 << std::cout; // No comments...
```

Which we avoid by passing object of our class as explicit, second parameter to our operator: `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const sound_ctl&)`.

You may want to check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68046121/14624729). This also will be helpful: [Overloading The IO Operators](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/overloading-the-io-operators/).

Also, note that it is a good practice to **mimic the built-in operators** in overloaded operators. So, your `operator++` **should return a reference** to the object on which it is called. And if you define a prefix, you should **also define a postfix** increment/decrement operators.

Comment: Thanks! Why shouldn't I declare them as member functions, though?

Comment: @Omri.B To summarize: For any object `o` then `o << x` is *either* the same as `o.operator<<(x)` (if `operator<<` is a member function ). or `operator<<(o, x)` (if `operator<<` is not a member function). This general rul of thumb is the same for all operators that can be overloaded.

Comment: @Omri.B check the latest edit. Added references to places where it all has already been covered.

Answer (score 1):

ALL of your operators are implemented incorrectly. See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/).

But, regarding `operator<<` specifically, it cannot be implemented as a member of the class, it must be a standalone function. And it needs to takes 2 parameters, the stream being written to, and the object being written.

Try this instead.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

class sound_ctl {
private:
    int _vol;
    bool _status;
public:
    sound_ctl() : _vol(50), _status(false) {};

    sound_ctl& operator++() {
        if (_vol <= 98) {
            _vol += 2;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    sound_ctl operator++(int) {
        sound_ctl tmp(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return tmp;
    }

    sount_ctl& operator--() {
        if (_vol >= 2) {
            _vol -= 2;
        }
        return *this;
    }


    sound_ctl operator--(int) {
        sound_ctl tmp(*this);
        --(*this);
        return tmp;
    }

    bool operator!() const {
        return !_status;
    }

    // even though this is inlined within the class declaration,
    // it is NOT actually a member of the class!
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const sound_ctl& ctl) {
        os << ctl._status << " Volume: " + ctl._vol << std::endl;
        return os;
    }
};

int main() {
    sound_ctl panel1;
    std::cout << panel1;
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use a member method:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

class sound_ctl {
private:
    int _vol;
    bool _status;
public:
    sound_ctl() : _vol(50), _status(false) {};

    sound_ctl& operator++() {
        if (_vol <= 98) {
            _vol += 2;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    sound_ctl operator++(int) {
        sound_ctl tmp(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return tmp;
    }

    sount_ctl& operator--() {
        if (_vol >= 2) {
            _vol -= 2;
        }
        return *this;
    }


    sound_ctl operator--(int) {
        sound_ctl tmp(*this);
        --(*this);
        return tmp;
    }

    bool operator!() const {
        return !_status;
    }

    void print(std::ostream &os) const {
        os << _status << " Volume: " + _vol << std::endl;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const sound_ctl& ctl) {
    ctl.print(os);
    return os;
}

int main() {
    sound_ctl panel1;
    std::cout << panel1;
}
```